# Creating Adaptive Leaderboard

Tags: javascript, css, html

The code below creates a leaderboard which ranks users from 1 to 10 and here is the result:

[image]

As you can see there are 10 users with their profile pictures and their names points etc... ranked from 1 to 10.

All the data needed to fill the leaderboard will come from the server (Which we have nothing to do with it for now, for example, an array which holds users points).

**Now the issue is I can't figure out how to modify the code to add this feature to my leaderboard:**

let's think of a user (a participant) who is looking at the leaderboard on his/her laptop to see which rank he/she achieved. ok...
we call him/her the **Main User.**

If the **Main User** is in between the 1st to 10th rank (the 5th rank for example) the leaderboard should only include him and highlight him:

[image]

If the **Main User** is Not ranked from 1 to 10, for example, his rank is 1025, then the leaderboard includes him in 10th rank place only to show him which rank he achieved:

[image]

Here is the code:

JS

```js
// this is the array that will hold all the profile objects
let profiles = [];

let profile1 = {};
profile1.name = "Jim Bob";
profile1.job = "Doctor";
profile1.points = 1500;
profile1.level = 15;
profile1.img = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/12.jpg";
profile1.imgDiamonds = "Diamonds.png";
profiles.push(profile1);

let profile2 = {};
profile2.name = "Jane tanha";
profile2.job = "Dentist";
profile2.points = 2000;
profile2.level = 1;
profile2.img = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/22.jpg";
profile2.imgDiamonds = "Diamonds.png";
profiles.push(profile2);

let profile3 = {};
profile3.name = "Mike Jones";
profile3.job = "Medic";
profile3.points = 4000;
profile3.level = 5;
profile3.img = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/22.jpg";
profile3.imgDiamonds = "Diamonds.png";
profiles.push(profile3);

let profile4 = {};
profile4.name = "Sally Peterson";
profile4.job = "Agriculture";
profile4.points = 1900;
profile4.level = 55;
profile4.img = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/24.jpg";
profile4.imgDiamonds = "Diamonds.png";
profiles.push(profile4);

let profile5 = {};
profile5.name = "Sally Peterson";
profile5.job = "Pumper";
profile5.points = 1100;
profile5.level = 4;
profile5.img = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/24.jpg";
profile5.imgDiamonds = "Diamonds.png";
profiles.push(profile5);

let profile6 = {};
profile6.name = "Sally Peterson";
profile6.job = "Mother";
profile6.points = 1400;
profile6.level = 85;
profile6.img = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/24.jpg";
profile6.imgDiamonds = "Diamonds.png";
profiles.push(profile6);

let profile7 = {};
profile7.name = "Sally Peterson";
profile7.job = "Nurse";
profile7.points = 1400;
profile7.level = 11;
profile7.img = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/24.jpg";
profile7.imgDiamonds = "Diamonds.png";
profiles.push(profile7);

let profile8 = {};
profile8.name = "Sally Peterson";
profile8.job = "Taxi Diver";
profile8.points = 1400;
profile8.level = 17;
profile8.img = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/24.jpg";
profile8.imgDiamonds = "Diamonds.png";
profiles.push(profile8);

let profile9 = {};
profile9.name = "Sally Peterson";
profile9.job = "High School Student";
profile9.points = 1400;
profile9.level = 37;
profile9.img = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/24.jpg";
profile9.imgDiamonds = "Diamonds.png";
profiles.push(profile9);

let profile10 = {};
profile10.name = "Sally Peterson";
profile10.job = "Student";
profile10.points = 1500;
profile10.level = 14;
profile10.img = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/24.jpg";
profile10.imgDiamonds = "Diamonds.png";
profiles.push(profile10);

// sort the array by points
// b - a will make highest first, swap them so a - b to make lowest first
profiles.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.points - a.points;
})


let count = 1;
profiles.forEach(function(entry) {
  let profilesDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('profiles')[Math.floor((count - 1) / 5)];

  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.className = "profilePic";
  img.src = entry.img;

  let imgDiamonds = document.createElement('img');
  imgDiamonds.className = "profileDia";
  imgDiamonds.src = entry.imgDiamonds;


  let profile = document.createElement('div');
  profile.className = "profile";
  profile.innerHTML = "<div class='name'>" + entry.name + "</div>";


  let job = document.createElement('span');
  job.className = "job";
  job.textContent = entry.job;
  profile.appendChild(job);
  profile.prepend(img);
  profile.prepend(imgDiamonds);


  let points = document.createElement('span');
  points.className = "points";
  points.textContent = entry.points;
  profile.appendChild(points);
  profile.prepend(img);
  profile.prepend(imgDiamonds);

  let level = document.createElement('span');
  level.className = "level";
  level.textContent = entry.level;
  profile.appendChild(level);
  profile.prepend(img);
  profile.prepend(imgDiamonds);

  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent = count + '. ';
  span.className = "count";
  profile.prepend(span);
  profilesDiv.appendChild(profile);
  count++;

});
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
}

.profile {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 100px 70px 0px 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.profile .name {
  margin-right: -210px;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.profile .job {
  margin-right: -210px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.profile .count {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-weight: 200;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff);
  color: #E6E0EC;
  font-size: 55px;
}

.profile img.profilePic {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -50px 70px 50px 90px;
  background: #2f293d;
  border: 1px solid #2f293d;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: .2rem .2rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.profile img.profileDia {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -10px 70px 50px 520px;
  width: 2%;
  height: auto;
}

.points {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px 100px 100px 450px;
  float: right;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff);
  color: #008CBA;
}

.level {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 35px 100px 100px 230px;
  float: right;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff);
  color: #ed0909;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  /* or 50% */
  border-radius: 30px;
  /* or 50% */
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="profiles"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="profiles"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To be more clear highlighting the desired ranks, names and changing rank 10 to 1025 or whatever rank number I want is my biggest problems... I can't even select a rank !!! :(

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: I'll edit to explain the issue

Comment: I would compare the leaderboard user to the logged in user (assuming it's stored somewhere). If the user matches, apply the appropriate CSS class to that "user" DOM element. Check to see if they are in the first ten, if they are apply the "green" class or w/e. Else, apply the red class and replace pos. 10 with user

Comment: applying the appropriate CSS class to that "user" DOM element and changing rank 10 to 1025 are Actually my biggest problems...

Comment: Thanks @Synoon for your edit...That really helps...

Answer (score 1):

This situation can be solved in a few ways. There isn't a good CSS property to solve this case.

One way is to pre-estimate the maximum amount of space each block would take and then fixing their dimensions. or use a grid based design approach that is mindful of these space constraints.

Second way is to reduce the font size of the numbers and try to fit them within their current block so that even when they are four digits long, its doesn't move the following content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Plus one ... I think you're talking about that right deviation in 10th rank right?! But my main problem is to add the explained feature to the leaderboard.

Comment: How do you calculate rank? does it come from the backend? Is calculating the current user's rank your problem?

Comment: you could also place everything inside a simple html table, oldschool but could work, be aware that you should split it in 2 tables for left right leaderboard otherwise html gets to complex